# How do I install the Flash debug player in Chrome?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, debugging

Chrome comes bundled with Flash now… Great, but how do I install the Flash debug player?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Disable the bundled plugin on `about:plugins` and then install the debug version.

EDIT: **be sure to click on "[+] Details"**, and only disable the version of Flash that is based on the Chrome directory (the 'built-in' one). *(Thanks @zeh for that additional hint in your comment)*

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. It's like the installer doesn't know about Chrome, since it did ask me to force close FireFox, but not Chrome. `about:plugins` doesn't show a new Flash plugin either.

Comment: Ok, I see. It seems there are just debug player available for ie and mozilla based browser :(

Comment: It does work. Go to `about:plugins`, **be sure to click on "[+] Details"**, and only disable the version of Flash that is based on the Chrome directory (the 'built-in' one). Then it'll use the plugin you have installed normally (the debug one) and is shared with Firefox.

Comment: As of the latest version of Chrome on Mac at this time (v43, 64-bit), this no longer works. The plugin must be manually replaced after each browser update (as per Justin Ohms' suggestion below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29711345/171599)

Answer (score 19):

1. Open the Google Chrome plugin settings (enter "chrome://plugins/" in the URL and hit enter) and find the Flash player plugin. Click on the details link to expand the plugin details.

**Plugin Screen**  [image: Plugin screen]!

**Plugin Screen showing Details** [image: Plugin Screen showing Details]

2A. If it says "Flash (2 files)" then check the ***location*** property of each entry and disable the one that resides in the ***Applications directory/Google Chrome/...*** directory (usually the first entry) by clicking the ***Disable*** link button. This is the disable button next to the "MIME Types" value not the Disable button aligned to the far left of the page (which disables both plugins).

2B. If there is only one entry, ie it doesn't say "Flash (2 files)", then download and install the newest Flash Player content debugger version **[here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)**. The Flash Player installer will require you to close any browsers before installation can complete. After installation is complete restart Chrome and go to step 1.

Your plugin screen should look similar to the *Plugin Screen showing Details* image shown above.

Answer (score 16):

As of April 2015 the NPAPI plugins won't work in Chrome.  And for some reason I was not able to get the Adobe  "Install Adobe Pepper Flash Player Debugger.app" installer to correctly update Chrome on OSX.  The installer would run but would not update Chrome.

If you find yourself in this situation you might try the following...

My hacky solution (after much frustration) was just to end-run around the installer and chrome to manually copy the installed plugin from where the installer was putting it, into the place chrome was expecting it.

The installer was placing here:

```
 /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin
```

Chrome was looking for it here:

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/42.0.2311.90/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Internet Plug-Ins/PepperFlash/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin
```

All I did was replace the bundled installed non-debug version of pepper flash  with the one debug version installed by the player.  This seemed to fix the problem.

YMMV

Comment: I have observed that FlashPlayer 17.0.0.169 PPAPI Debug Version for OSX does not install properly in Chrome.  This answer worked for me.  I am assuming when Chrome updates itself we will have to manually replace the plugin again.

Comment: @BrodyRobertson  I am assuming the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Now it changed once again

1. download *Flash Player content debugger for Opera and Chromium* from [Adobe debug flash downloads](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html)
2. run/install this
3. find which flash plugin used

   - open chrome://plugins/
   - expand details
   - get something like *C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\47.0.2526.106\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll*
4. replace this file with renamed one from

   - 64 bit OS version

     - C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_[some actual version].dll
   - 32 bit OS version

     - C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_[some actual version].dll

This worked for win 7 x64, other Wins-s should be almost same

To get flash logs for Chrome you need

1. create mm.cfg file in
   %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System

`ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1`

2. restart Chrome
3. logs stored in different, than FF location -
   %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\WritableRoot\Logs

Comment: plugin cannot be loaded for me on win10 64bit

Comment: @fideldonson, do you need it _per se_ or for webdriver?
With new 57th Chrome there are changes, which I not checked yet, but works like a charm for chromedriver (sometimes you need to add a param with version _--ppapi-flash-version_ flag)

Comment: I went with another solution (firefox...) - thanks for getting back to me though

Answer (score 1):

[image: Enabling Flash Player(Debugger) on Windows 8]
Please make sure your Chrome auto updates are on.
Open the Chrome browser and type "chrome://plugins/" in the URL and then you should be able to see two plugins listed under "Adobe Flash Player" section.
Disable the "PPAPI" one, to allow the Windows version of FP to take over the precedence.

Still Facing issues: 
Can't find the "NPAPI" = "C:\windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_14_0_0_145.dll
" version i.e., there is only one version listed there "PPAPI" one.

Solution:
Then need to kill all the Chrome process(Plugins) running post/pre installation.
Windows Task Manager Kill all Chrome processes.

Check again in: chrome://plugins/ Now it should be listed there.

Answer (score 1):

In current Chrome (version 47) you don't see installed debug flash player version. You will see only bundled flash player that goes with the browser.

Replacing file as replied here by @dimkin is working. But during update, Chrome will overwrite files and you need to repeat it once in a while.

If you create shortcut for Chrome with command line argument **--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash**, it will ignore bundled flash player. And if you have Debug version installed, Chrome will use it. You will see it in [chrome://plugins/](http://chrome://plugins/):

[image]