# Calculating a Score

Tags: actionscript-3

I simply want to calculate a score that increments by one each time.

```
function calcScore(event:Event):void{ 
    if(MainChar.hitTestObject(thecoin)) { 
        coinScore += 1;
        coinScoreLabel.text = String(coinScore);
    } 
}
```

I made coinScore global.

Now when I run the game there are no errors and I don't see the label showing anything at all it just stays blank and wont display a number.

Comment: You don't need to cast `coinScore` as a `String`.

Comment: Do you have Flash Player Debugger installed?

Comment: I don't marco and I'll try that now Patrick! :)

Comment: if(MainChar.hitTestObject(thecoin)){ 
 coinScore += 1;
 coinScoreLabel.text = (coinScore);
 } 
 }

Comment: Also, instead of having to re-define the label everytime, you can just use [Bindable] variable to bind it to the MXML element. That way, when you re-define the variable, the screen is automatically updated.

Comment: still doesnt work :( And I have no clue what MXML is, I'm new to this and im trying to use a method that previously worked before but it isnt now

Comment: Did you install Flash Player Debugger? Are you using Chrome?

Comment: can you give me a link marco? yes chrome :)

Comment: I forgot to mention i have a load of collectables, coin1, coin2, coin3 etc, how would i go about incorporating all of these, i know i can make an array but not comfortable in doing so. So whats a way even though a long way of doing it, multiple if statement?

Comment: I'm really grateful for your guys help btw :) Still trying to fix the score system :/

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu I don't think he's using flex.

Comment: @user3564111 that's another question.

What type of object is `coinScoreLabel`?

Comment: Download the Flash Debugger here https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html
and then see what message error it shows when you collect a coin.

Comment: coinScoreLabel is a dynamic text field

Comment: attempting to download it now

Comment: Enabling Flash debugger on Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804424/how-do-i-install-the-flash-debug-player-in-chrome

Comment: ah man, nevermind im not having much luck with it, I'll just keep trying at it and look around YT. I'm just unsure why this technique doesnt work when it had before, Im sorry Marco :( It looks real complex, I tried disabling my flash and I dont know where to go after that to debug

Comment: You're not suppose to debug the code, you're just suppose to have it installed. If your code has an error, when you collect the coin (playing the game), the function will be called an if there's an error a message will pop-up.

Comment: if you're in the flash IDE, go to file>Publish Settings and check "permit debugging"

Comment: I have done and then what do I do?

Comment: Do you get any errors? What class is coinScoreLabel? if you trace (coinScore) what comes out?

Comment: I dont think i have assigned a class to it at all, I tried tracing it 0 all the time but 1 random attempt it shot up tp 37 :/

Comment: Just tried several other times, it jumps to a random number and sometimes increments by 2 sometimes 1

Comment: Anyone else have a suggestion, still trying to solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem is **font embedding**.

Embed the font and will work.