# Find out what or who calls/triggers shockwave/activeX/flash

Tags: flash, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, shockwave

We sometimes see this bar "A plugin (shockwave flash) is not responding" on web pages which often freezes the page.

[image: not responding]

While trying to debug it, I can't figure out who is calling this shockwave flash, Are there any tools that can give a clue who initiated this or any flash?

Are there any tools that can give a hint of what is the cause of this?

Comment: Could be invoked by an advertisement iframe. Use devtools network panel to catch the initiator of flash media download, or Ctrl-Shift-F to search all code for text like `flash`, `"object"`, `<object` and so on.

Comment: Thats right, But there are many, I am not sure which one exactly is causing this issue! To make it even more complicated, it only happens randomly

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any tools that can give a hint of what is the cause of this?

You can try installing the Flash Player **Debugger** version which might give you hint messages.

See this [Adobe guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-flash-player-content-debugger-in-google-chrome.html) for setting up in Chrome browser. Also you can try the *2015*-dated solutions in this other [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804424/how-do-i-install-the-flash-debug-player-in-chrome).

> ...what is the cause of this?

Usually it's the running code in the SWF (Flash file) that causes this error. Not so much caused by an external caller/callee of the SWF.

For example : A `while` loop that does not get all required conditions to end/break will run forever (freezing the system) so browser eventually gives you the *timeout* error & option to `stop plugin` as shown in your image.

Other examples include code that should really be in a `try / catch` format but if there's only some "do this task" command & no error is caught or handled then the app is stuck for a long time.